# CDK Unable to create a CloudWatch Logs SubscriptionFilter

Tags: python, aws-cdk

I tried to create a Cloud Watch Logs Subscription Filter with CDK framework without any success.

```py
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_kinesis,
    aws_iam,
    aws_logs,
    core
)


class LambdaStack(core.Stack):
    def __init__(self, app: core.App, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(app, id, **kwargs)

        stream = aws_kinesis.Stream(
            self,
            "datalake-stream",
            stream_name="datalake-stream"
        )

        role = aws_iam.Role(
            self,
            "datalake-role",
            role_name="datalake-role",
            assumed_by=aws_iam.ServicePrincipal('logs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com')
        )

        role.add_to_policy(aws_iam.PolicyStatement(
            actions=['kinesis:PutRecord'],
            resources=[stream.stream_arn],
        ))

        role.add_to_policy(aws_iam.PolicyStatement(
            actions=['iam:PassRole'],
            resources=[role.role_arn],
        ))

        log_group = aws_logs.LogGroup(
            self,
            "datalake-logroup",
            log_group_name="/test")

        aws_logs.SubscriptionFilter(
            self,
            "-datalake-subscriptionfilter",
            log_group=log_group,
            filter_pattern=aws_logs.FilterPattern().all_events,
            destination=stream
        )


app = core.App()
LambdaStack(app, "cwllogstos3", env={'region': 'eu-west-1'})
app.synth()
```

I got these errors:

$ cdk deploy

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "infra.py", line 52, in
>   
>       LambdaStack(app, "cwllogstos3", env={'region': 'eu-west-1'})   File
>   "/Users/enrico.pesce/Documents/GitHub/cwllogstos3/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_runtime.py",
>   line 66, in **call**
>       inst = super().**call**(*args, **kwargs)   File "infra.py", line 47, in **init**
>       destination=stream   File "/Users/enrico.pesce/Documents/GitHub/cwllogstos3/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_runtime.py",
>   line 66, in **call**
>       inst = super().**call**(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/enrico.pesce/Documents/GitHub/cwllogstos3/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aws_cdk/aws_logs/**init**.py",
>   line 2060, in **init**
>       jsii.create(SubscriptionFilter, self, [scope, id, props])   File "/Users/enrico.pesce/Documents/GitHub/cwllogstos3/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/**init**.py",
>   line 207, in create
>       args=_make_reference_for_native(self, args),   File "/Users/enrico.pesce/Documents/GitHub/cwllogstos3/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/**init**.py",
>   line 119, in _make_reference_for_native
>       return [_make_reference_for_native(kernel, i) for i in d]   File "/Users/enrico.pesce/Documents/GitHub/cwllogstos3/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/**init**.py",
>   line 119, in 
>       return [_make_reference_for_native(kernel, i) for i in d]   File "/Users/enrico.pesce/Documents/GitHub/cwllogstos3/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/**init**.py",
>   line 124, in _make_reference_for_native
>       return _make_reference_for_native(kernel, struct_data)   File "/Users/enrico.pesce/Documents/GitHub/cwllogstos3/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/**init**.py",
>   line 117, in _make_reference_for_native
>       return {k: _make_reference_for_native(kernel, v) for k, v in d.items()}   File
>   "/Users/enrico.pesce/Documents/GitHub/cwllogstos3/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/**init**.py",
>   line 117, in 
>       return {k: _make_reference_for_native(kernel, v) for k, v in d.items()}   File
>   "/Users/enrico.pesce/Documents/GitHub/cwllogstos3/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/**init**.py",
>   line 130, in _make_reference_for_native
>       d.**jsii__type** = "Object" AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute '**jsii__type**' Subprocess exited with error 1

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
filter_pattern=aws_logs.FilterPattern().all_events
```

You're passing a reference to a method `all_events`. But you should pass an instance of the `IFilterPattern` interface.

Try changing it to:

```
filter_pattern=aws_logs.FilterPattern().all_events()
```